# Is there a guide to Rails for experienced Rubyists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

A few years back, I started learning Ruby/Rails from some beginner's guide for Rails. I had learned the basics of Rails then, such as some of the convention over configuration for models and routes, and how to use helpers etc. However, I didn't stick with it long because I found Sinatra soon thereafter, and decided I personally liked it much better.

I ended up really loving Ruby though, and I've written a lot of Ruby since, almost none of which was for any Rails project. However, it turns out that the majority of Ruby work available is for Rails applications. So I'd like to take another stab at Rails now.

Now, the reference is great and has a lot of good information, but I only look at a reference for the particular things I need and don't remember off the top of my head. But it's unlikely I'll come across details like `script/console` in the reference.

I also don't want to go through beginners' tutorials as they seem to all assume that you don't know Ruby or programming even. I don't want to wade through explanations of what a conditional statement is or details about Ruby which I already know interspersed among the Rails information.

I just want a succinct, no-nonsense overview/guide to Rails (without Ruby information intermixed). Does it exist?

Comment: +1 for taking the time to learn Ruby first, even though that might not have been your first intention. Knowing Ruby, even at an intermediate level, will make Rails a lot easier to fathom. Rails development moves fast so it's hard to find good documentation. The internet is full of stale and out-of-date information that makes no sense when trying to use a current version of Rails, so I've found the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) to be very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The r[ails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are by far my favorite resource!

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: The rails guides are a great resource. I refer to them as a high level resource. Usually followed by a visit to http://api.rubyonrails.org/. Even after 4 years of Rails work I find them helpful.

Comment: Yeah, they kinda make up for the API but even that is getting better.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend [The Rails 3 Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601661) for a good introduction to Rails at both a high level and fine grained details, without the "Welcome to Programming" tone.

Answer (score 5):

I just got this one, and it looks really good so far:

http://pragprog.com/titles/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications

Answer (score 5):

Certainly take a look at http://railscasts.com for lots of different Rails matters. It's a very important resource.

Another resource that many use (i have the book as well) is Rails Example :

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this [advanced Ruby on Rails configuration guides](https://hixonrails.com/ruby-on-rails-tutorials/). It's a relatively young yet still growing resource full of end to end explanations on how to integrate Ruby on Rails framework with multiple tools such as commonly used loggers, static code analysis tools, useful testing frameworks, and continuous integration providers.